# code changes in the docker container as a root user

Tags: docker, root

I'm experimenting with the docker concept for C++ development. I wrote a Dockerfile that includes instructions for installing all of the necessary libraries and tools. CMake is being used to build C++ code and install binaries. Because of a specific use case, the binaries should be executed as root user. I'm running the docker container with the following command.

`docker run -it --rm -u 0 -v $(pwd):/mnt  buildmcu:focal`

The issue now is that I am a root user inside the Docker container, and if I make any code changes/create a new file inside the Docker container, I am getting a permission error on the host machine If I try to access it.I need to run the `sudo chmod ...` to change the permissions.Is there any way to allow the source modification in docker container and host machine without permission error?

Comment: Why are you using `-u 0` and not your user ID

Comment: I need to keep generated binary in `/var/scripts` folder then only it will execute,so for that I need to be a root user in the docker container as `sudo` is not working inside docker.

Comment: You might find it easier to think of the Docker image like a compiled binary, and the container like a running instance of that binary.  So in the same way you don't usually open up a debugger and try to change the code inside your running application, the standard model is that you wouldn't make changes inside a container; instead, build a new image and run a new container from it.